# Xmonad Layout Follow up

Tags: haskell, xmonad

This is a follow up to a question that I had before. I know about the DoRectFloat/RationalRect modules and such, but, I've tried to write proper Haskell and it either doesn't compile, or it compiles and doesn't do what I want.

(These are floating windows that I want) What I want is a layout like
[image]

How would I go about writing this?

My current Xmonad Config:

```
--my XMonad Config
--xterm, contrib, feh, and nitrogen are used here

import XMonad
import Data.Monoid
import XMonad.Util.Run
import XMonad.Layout.Gaps
import XMonad.Util.SpawnOnce
import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import System.Exit
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers 
import XMonad.ManageHook
import qualified DBus as D
import qualified DBus.Client as D
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as String
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import System.IO
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map        as M
import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86

-- The preferred terminal program, which is used in a binding below and by
-- certain contrib modules.
--
myTerminal      = "xterm"

-- Whether focus follows the mouse pointer.
myFocusFollowsMouse :: Bool
myFocusFollowsMouse = True

-- Whether clicking on a window to focus also passes the click to the window
myClickJustFocuses :: Bool
myClickJustFocuses = False

-- Width of the window border in pixels.
--
myBorderWidth   = 2

-- modMask lets you specify which modkey you want to use. The default
-- is mod1Mask ("left alt").  You may also consider using mod3Mask
-- ("right alt"), which does not conflict with emacs keybindings. The
-- "windows key" is usually mod4Mask.
--
myModMask       = mod1Mask

-- The default number of workspaces (virtual screens) and their names.
-- By default we use numeric strings, but any string may be used as a
-- workspace name. The number of workspaces is determined by the length
-- of this list.
--
-- A tagging example:
--
-- > workspaces = ["web", "irc", "code" ] ++ map show [4..9]
--
myWorkspaces    = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

-- Border colors for unfocused and focused windows, respectively.
--
myNormalBorderColor  = "#0a0b11"
myFocusedBorderColor = "#ace5e0"
 
--soda



------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Key bindings. Add, modify or remove key bindings here.
--
myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $

    -- launch a terminal
    [ ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_Return), spawn $ XMonad.terminal conf)

    -- launch dmenu
    , ((modm,               xK_d     ), spawn "dmenu_run")

    --launch ff
    , ((modm,               xK_p     ), spawn "brave")
    --vol
      , ((modm,               xK_F8     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle")
      , ((modm,               xK_i      ), spawn "pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-speaker")
      , ((modm,               xK_o      ), spawn "pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-headphones")
      , ((modm,               xK_F6     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 50%")
      , ((modm,               xK_Up     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +3%")
      , ((modm,               xK_Down     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -3%")
      --, ((0, xK_Right), spawn "xbacklight -dec 10")
        --, ((0, xK_Left), spawn "xbacklight -inc 10")
      --lol
      , ((0,               xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume    ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%")
      , ((0,               xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume    ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%")
      , ((0,               xF86XK_AudioMute     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle")
    -- launch gmrun
    --, ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_p     ), spawn "gmrun")
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_v     ), spawn "virtualbox")
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_b     ), spawn "xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.5")
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_z     ), spawn "xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 1")

    --master settings /gnome
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_f     ), spawn "gnome-control-center")
    --eq
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_u     ), spawn "pulseeffects")

    --lock (you need i3lock installed on your system)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_x     ), spawn "i3lock -i ~/.config/i3/spart.png")

    --fm
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_g     ), spawn "pcmanfm")
    -- close focused window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_c     ), kill)

     -- Rotate through the available layout algorithms
    , ((modm,               xK_space ), sendMessage NextLayout)

    --  Reset the layouts on the current workspace to default
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_space ), setLayout $ XMonad.layoutHook conf)

    -- Resize viewed windows to the correct size
    , ((modm,               xK_n     ), refresh)

    -- Move focus to the next window
    , ((modm,               xK_Tab   ), windows W.focusDown)

    -- Move focus to the next window
    , ((modm,               xK_j     ), windows W.focusDown)

    -- Move focus to the previous window
    , ((modm,               xK_k     ), windows W.focusUp  )

    -- Move focus to the master window
    , ((modm,               xK_m     ), windows W.focusMaster  )

    -- Swap the focused window and the master window
    , ((modm,               xK_Return), windows W.swapMaster)

    -- Swap the focused window with the next window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_j     ), windows W.swapDown  )

    -- Swap the focused window with the previous window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_k     ), windows W.swapUp    )

    -- Shrink the master area
    , ((modm,               xK_h     ), sendMessage Shrink)

    -- Expand the master area
    , ((modm,               xK_l     ), sendMessage Expand)

    -- Push window back into tiling
    , ((modm,               xK_t     ), withFocused $ windows . W.sink)

    -- Increment the number of windows in the master area
    , ((modm              , xK_comma ), sendMessage (IncMasterN 1))

    -- Deincrement the number of windows in the master area
    , ((modm              , xK_period), sendMessage (IncMasterN (-1)))

    -- Toggle the status bar gap
    -- Use this binding with avoidStruts from Hooks.ManageDocks.
    -- See also the statusBar function from Hooks.DynamicLog.
    --
    -- , ((modm              , xK_b     ), sendMessage ToggleStruts)

    -- Quit xmonad
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_q     ), io (exitWith ExitSuccess))

    -- Restart xmonad
    , ((modm              , xK_q     ), spawn "xmonad --recompile; xmonad --restart")

    -- Run xmessage with a summary of the default keybindings (useful for beginners)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_slash ), spawn ("echo \"" ++ help ++ "\" | xmessage -file -"))
    ]
    ++

    --
    -- mod-[1..9], Switch to workspace N
    -- mod-shift-[1..9], Move client to workspace N
    --
    [((m .|. modm, k), windows $ f i)
        | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]
    ++

    --
    -- mod-{w,e,r}, Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3
    -- mod-shift-{w,e,r}, Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3
    --
    [((m .|. modm, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f))
        | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_w, xK_e, xK_r] [0..]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]


------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Mouse bindings: default actions bound to mouse events
--
myMouseBindings (XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $

    -- mod-button1, Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging
    [ ((modm, button1), (\w -> focus w >> mouseMoveWindow w
                                       >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button2, Raise the window to the top of the stack
    , ((modm, button2), (\w -> focus w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button3, Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging
    , ((modm, button3), (\w -> focus w >> mouseResizeWindow w
                                       >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- you may also bind events to the mouse scroll wheel (button4 and button5)
    ]

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Layouts:

-- You can specify and transform your layouts by modifying these values.
-- If you change layout bindings be sure to use 'mod-shift-space' after
-- restarting (with 'mod-q') to reset your layout state to the new
-- defaults, as xmonad preserves your old layout settings by default.
--
-- The available layouts.  Note that each layout is separated by |||,
-- which denotes layout choice.
--
myLayout = tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| theg ||| Full
  where
    tiled = spacing 35 $ Tall nmaster delta ratio
    theg = gaps [(U,18), (R,23)] $ Tall 1 (3/100) (1/2)
    nmaster = 1
    ratio = 1/2
    delta = 3/100
     

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Window rules:

-- Execute arbitrary actions and WindowSet manipulations when managing
-- a new window. You can use this to, for example, always float a
-- particular program, or have a client always appear on a particular
-- workspace.
--
-- To find the property name associated with a program, use
-- > xprop | grep WM_CLASS
-- and click on the client you're interested in.
--
-- To match on the WM_NAME, you can use 'title' in the same way that
-- 'className' and 'resource' are used below.
-- --> (doRectFloat $ W.RationalRect 0.5 0.5 0.9 0.9)

myManageHook = composeAll . concat $
    [ [className =? "mpv"        --> doFloat]
    , [className =? "xterm"        --> (doRectFloat $ W.RationalRect 0.5 0.5 0.4 0.4)]

    --, [className =? c --> (doRectFloat $ W.RationalRect 0.5 0.5 0.9 0.9)| c <- mylol]
    , [manageDocks]
    ]
    where
    myTop = ["xterm htop"]
    myTerm = ["xterm"]
    myVis = ["xterm vis"]

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Event handling

-- * EwmhDesktops users should change this to ewmhDesktopsEventHook
--
-- Defines a custom handler function for X Events. The function should
-- return (All True) if the default handler is to be run afterwards. To
-- combine event hooks use mappend or mconcat from Data.Monoid.
--
myEventHook = mempty

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Status bars and logging

-- Perform an arbitrary action on each internal state change or X event.
-- See the 'XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog' extension for examples.
--
myLogHook = return ()

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Startup hook

-- Perform an arbitrary action each time xmonad starts or is restarted
-- with mod-q.  Used by, e.g., XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace to initialize
-- per-workspace layout choices.
--
-- By default, do nothing.
myStartupHook :: X ()
myStartupHook = do
     spawn "nitrogen --restore &"
     spawn "picom &" 
     spawn "xterm vis"
     spawn "xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr"
     spawn "xset b off"


------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Now run xmonad with all the defaults we set up.

-- Run xmonad with the settings you specify. No need to modify this.
--
main = do
     xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 0 ~/.xmonad/taskbarrc"
     xmonad $ docks defaults


-- A structure containing your configuration settings, overriding
-- fields in the default config. Any you don't override, will
-- use the defaults defined in xmonad/XMonad/Config.hs
--
-- No need to modify this.
--
defaults = def {
      -- simple stuff
        terminal           = myTerminal,
        focusFollowsMouse  = myFocusFollowsMouse,
        clickJustFocuses   = myClickJustFocuses,
        borderWidth        = myBorderWidth,
        modMask            = myModMask,
        workspaces         = myWorkspaces,
        normalBorderColor  = myNormalBorderColor,
        focusedBorderColor = myFocusedBorderColor,

      -- key bindings
        keys               = myKeys,
        mouseBindings      = myMouseBindings,

      -- hooks, layouts
        layoutHook         = myLayout,
        manageHook         = myManageHook,
        handleEventHook    = myEventHook,
        logHook            = myLogHook,
        startupHook        = myStartupHook
    }

-- | Finally, a copy of the default bindings in simple textual tabular format.
help :: String
help = unlines ["The default modifier key is 'alt'. Default keybindings:",
    "",
    "-- launching and killing programs",
    "mod-Shift-Enter  Launch xterminal",
    "mod-p            Launch dmenu",
    "mod-Shift-p      Launch gmrun",
    "mod-Shift-c      Close/kill the focused window",
    "mod-Space        Rotate through the available layout algorithms",
    "mod-Shift-Space  Reset the layouts on the current workSpace to default",
    "mod-n            Resize/refresh viewed windows to the correct size",
    "",
    "-- move focus up or down the window stack",
    "mod-Tab        Move focus to the next window",
    "mod-Shift-Tab  Move focus to the previous window",
    "mod-j          Move focus to the next window",
    "mod-k          Move focus to the previous window",
    "mod-m          Move focus to the master window",
    "",
    "-- modifying the window order",
    "mod-Return   Swap the focused window and the master window",
    "mod-Shift-j  Swap the focused window with the next window",
    "mod-Shift-k  Swap the focused window with the previous window",
    "",
    "-- resizing the master/slave ratio",
    "mod-h  Shrink the master area",
    "mod-l  Expand the master area",
    "",
    "-- floating layer support",
    "mod-t  Push window back into tiling; unfloat and re-tile it",
    "",
    "-- increase or decrease number of windows in the master area",
    "mod-comma  (mod-,)   Increment the number of windows in the master area",
    "mod-period (mod-.)   Deincrement the number of windows in the master area",
    "",
    "-- quit, or restart",
    "mod-Shift-q  Quit xmonad",
    "mod-q        Restart xmonad",
    "mod-[1..9]   Switch to workSpace N",
    "",
    "-- Workspaces & screens",
    "mod-Shift-[1..9]   Move client to workspace N",
    "mod-{w,e,r}        Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3",
    "mod-Shift-{w,e,r}  Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3",
    "",
    "-- Mouse bindings: default actions bound to mouse events",
    "mod-button1  Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging",
    "mod-button2  Raise the window to the top of the stack",
    "mod-button3  Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging"]
```

Comment: isn't `Mirror (Tall nmaster inc r)` that layout?

Comment: On startup it isn't. @lsmor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting the three windows, use `xterm`'s `-class` option to modify the `WM_CLASS` property it attaches to its window, choosing a different and unique class for each of the three. Then you can select for that class in your manage hook to only match the right window.

Comment: You're a life-saver.